# unable to launch chorme using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to launch chrome using selenium webdriver. I have set the property with the correct path and still, I am getting the following error. The path to the driver executable must be set by the `webdriver.chrome.driver` system property

[image]

Comment: Welcome :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `.exe` in your path, use the below path

```
"C:\\Users\\PRATIKSHA\\DOWNLOADS\\chromedriver.exe"
```

and you need to set property for chromedriver `webdriver.chrome.driver`

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\PRATIKSHA\\DOWNLOADS\\chromedriver.exe");
```

See the sample code from chromedriver doc [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)

Comment: If you are demonstrating the _windows_ usage it's better to represent the path within double quotes.

Comment: @DebanjanB Done!